# Obtain Date of Field change in Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

I have a saved search built out in Netsuite but need additional results.

Specifically, for each record in the system I have a checkbox field titled, "Reviewed by Jerry."

In the saved search results, how do I add a column of the date the "Reviewed by Jerry" tab was changed from "F" to "T"?

I've tried to add a field in the results tab where the field is "Reviewed by Jerry (Custom body)" but when I try to add, it throws the error, "Date functions may only be used with date type fields".  Obviously it's not a date field but I just need to know how to obtain the date from that field change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the System Notes join to see the changes that have been made to a record.

In the criteria tab add the filters:

- System Notes... Field = Reviewed by Jerry
- System Notes... New Value = T

In the results tab add a column:

- System Notes.. Date

Comment: That works but it is limited as it repeats records because there are other fields included that also have System Notes new values as being T.

Comment: The first filter (System Notes..Field) should remove those

Comment: Obviously I'm new to Netsuite and might be missing something but there is no option to select "System Notes... Field = Reviewed by Jerry".  There is the option to select "Reviewed by Jerry (Custom Body)". Am I missing some part of the Description part of the Criteria tab?

Comment: In the filter box, select `System Notes Fields`. This will bring up a pop-up to select which joined System Notes field you want to filter - choose `Field` from that list. You will then shown a select box where you can type in the name of the field you want to filter - start typing `Reviewed by Jerry` and it should come up and allow you to select it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That worked like a charm!  I didn't know you had to type the Reviewed by Jerry into the pop up box.